# How to find the above summation upto infinity?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to find the summation of this series upto infinity?

$$\frac{1}{1.2}+\frac{1}{3.4}+\frac{1}{5.6}+\cdots\infty$$

Actually I know how to find the summation of a telescopic sequence like $\frac{1}{(1×2)}+\frac{1}{(2×3)}+\frac{1}{(3×4)},...$ upto $\infty$. But how to find the summation of the above series upto infinity? As far as I know the above series is not a telescopic series.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: But how to proceed after that?

Comment: I don't think that the above series is a telescopic series

Comment: Thanks for helping.